# Resolution discrepancy between Windows Settings and 3rd party program

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, intel-graphics

I'm running the 64-bit version of Windows 10, version 1703 and Intel 530 integrated graphics. I have been having problems with my aftermarket GPU the last few months, and during the course of uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers, I noticed that my resolution as listed in Display settings (within Windows 10) are different than what is listed in Speccy.

For the sake of this question, I have uninstalled the GPU/associated drivers and am running my integrated graphics (Intel 530). I have both of my monitors set at the native resolution of 1080p (1920 by 1080). In Windows 10 Display settings under Scale and Layout, I have the "size of text, apps, and other items" set to 150% (recommended). When I look at the resolution in Speccy, it tells me that the Current Resolution and Work resolution are 1280x720 and 1280x680 respectively. When I switch the Scaling in Display Settings (size of text, apps...) to 100% (where the resolution is still set at 1920x1080), Speccy shows the Current/Work Resolution to be 1920x1080 and 1920x1040 respectively.

This never happened before (I noticed it just now). In the past, whether using my integrated graphics, the first aftermarket GPU I bought, or the current aftermarket GPU, the resolution has always matched from Display Settings to Speccy, and I have always had the scaling set to 150%. Is it showing the resolution in Speccy as 1280x720 because the text, etc. is "magnified" in the scaling section of Display settings, and if so, why was this never an issue before now?

Please advise. Again, I've uninstalled the aftermarket card and all of the related drivers and am running the [factory] integrated graphics to simplify this question.

Here's the 150% scaling

[image]

[image]

And the 100% scaling

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 1280 would correspond to Windows telling the app to work at a particular resolution (1280) and then Windows scaling the app up but 150% to your "native" 1920 resolution.  It's a reasonably robust way to force non-HighDPI aware applications to work with scaling. I'm not sure why you would be seeing a difference in behaviour, I'd suspect that it could be a driver update that exposes a hardware scaling method...

Comment: @Mokubai - You are correct.  I suspect the problem is with Speccy itself.  I assume you are running Windows 10 Intel drivers that have specific support for 1703 and 1709?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, the drivers are up to date for the Intel 530 adapter. As for Speccy, it's the most recent version. After I posted this, I re-installed the aftermarket GPU and most recent drivers. It's a GTX 1060 6GB, so obviously, those are Nvidia drivers. The same thing is happening with the integrated graphics and the aftermarket GPU. I suppose I could try and roll back the driver on the Intel display adapter and see if that does anything. But am I correct in understanding that the numbers in Speccy don't accurately reflect the resolution (that it just shows up that way due to scaling)?

Comment: I just ran DirectX Diagnostic tool, and that program shows the resolution to be 1929x1080 on both displays. So it must be an issue with Speccy. Again, I am currently using the GTX 1060 with the most recent drivers. Thanks for weighing in, both of you.

Comment: @Fred yes, if Speccy does not announce to the operating system that it willingly works with display scaling and will handle it appropriately then Windows will simply tell it that a lower resolution is available and do the scaling for it. To me what you are seeing is what I would expect to be normal behaviour. I can post an answer to that effect if you like.